# Template literals cause lost type information in mapped object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I have run into a seemingly intractable problem with a tool I am writing. The tool allows defining all action types, actions, selectors, and reducer functions based on the shape of an initial state object. Before I delve into specifics, let me first describe the intended usage.

It begins with an enum that defines all the keys for properties inside the state, such as:

```
enum MyEnum {
  TEST = 'test1',
  TEST2 = 'test2',
}
```

Using the enum, we then define an initial state.

```
const exampleState = {
  [MyEnum.TEST]: new Entry<string>(),
  [MyEnum.TEST2]: new Entry<number>(),
};
```

Please note that, beyond the generic type parameter used on the Entry class, using type annotation to declare this state object is unnecessary and would defeat the tool's purpose because the initial state is the source of truth for the state's shape and types.

Skipping other initialization steps included in the full version of this tool, we can use individual functions belonging to it independently without ill-effect.

Create action types:

```
const actionTypes = createActionTypes<typeof MyEnum>(MyEnum);
```

Create actions:

```
const actions = createActions<typeof MyEnum, typeof exampleState>(actionTypes, MyEnum);
```

If I start writing some code, I get syntax suggestions showing that this object has two functions: "test1" and "test2".

[image]

If I run the functions with correct and incorrect parameters, I get the intended effect. The first entry is a string, so the parameter should also be a string. Typescript correctly throws errors when calling the test1 and test2 functions with a number and a string, respectively.

[image]

However, it's boring using the keys as function names. It'd be much nicer to call the test1 function something like `updateTest1` because that is what the action does.

I have a second creator function to call, which does just that.

```
const aliasedActions = createAliasedActions(actions, MyEnum);
```

Like actions before this, I get proper syntax suggestions when I start accessing the properties of `aliasedActions`, only this time, I see "`updateTest1`" and "`updateTest2`"

[image]

Next is where I run into a problem. When I call any of the functions with a string or a number, TypeScript does not throw an error on any of them!

```
aliasedActions.updateTest1(1); // okay
aliasedActions.updateTest1('1'); // okay
aliasedActions.updateTest2(1); // okay
aliasedActions.updateTest2('1'); // okay
```

After inspecting the types, the parameter appears to be a union of all the possible types (`string | number | undefined`) instead of the specific type required, given the schema of the initial state (`updateTest1` should take `string | undefined` and `updateTest2` should take `number | undefined`).

[image]

What happened?

The type definition for `Action` takes a generic type parameter for the key of the initial state and uses it to reference the type for the parameter "payload" (`S[K]['value']`).

```
class Entry<T = any> {
  value?: T;
  constructor(
    value?: T,
  ) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

type MyState<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
> = {
  [key in E[keyof E]]: Entry
};

type Action<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
  K extends E[keyof E],
> = (
  payload: S[K]['value'],
) => ({
  type: ActionTypes<E>[K],
  key: K,
  payload: S[K]['value'],
});

type Actions<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
> = {
  [K in E[keyof E]]: Action<E, S, K>
};
```

The above code appears correct, and testing of `actions` confirms it. However, `aliasedActions` has a somewhat different type of definition, and this is where I cannot figure out what I should do differently.

```
type ActionName<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  K extends E[keyof E],
> = `update${Capitalize<K>}`;

type AliasedActions<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
> = {
  [K in E[keyof E] as ActionName<E, K>]: Action<E, S, E[keyof E]>;
};
```

Since within the mapped object type, I assert `K`, a value in the enum, as a template literal, it appears as though I can no longer use `K` as the third generic type parameter for `Action`. Hence, `Action<E, S, E[keyof E]>` instead of `Action<E, S, K>`. However, a side effect is that `Action<E, S, E[keyof E]>` makes the parameter "payload" a union of all the potential types instead of a specific type.

I need help figuring out a way around this. It should be simple, but nothing I have tried worked. Is there some way I can pass in `K` as the original type yet still have the key remain `ActionName<E, K>`?

Example code for testing:

```
class Entry<T = any> {

  value?: T;

  constructor(
    value?: T,
  ) {
    this.value = value;
  }

}

type MyState<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
> = {
  [key in E[keyof E]]: Entry
};

type Action<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
  K extends E[keyof E],
> = (
  payload: S[K]['value'],
) => ({
  type: ActionTypes<E>[K],
  key: K,
  payload: S[K]['value'],
});

type Actions<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
> = {
  [K in E[keyof E]]: Action<E, S, K>
};

type ActionTypes<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
> = {
  [K in E[keyof E]]: ActionTypeName<E, K>
};

type ActionTypeName<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  K extends E[keyof E],
> = `UPDATE_${Uppercase<K>}`;

type ActionName<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  K extends E[keyof E],
> = `update${Capitalize<K>}`;

type AliasedActions<
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
> = {
  [K in E[keyof E] as ActionName<E, K>]: Action<E, S, E[keyof E]>;
};

const createActionTypeName = <
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  K extends E[keyof E] = E[keyof E],
>(key: K): ActionTypeName<E, K> => {
  const postFix = key.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<K>;
  return `UPDATE_${postFix}`;
};

const createActionTypes = <
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
>(
  keys: E,
): ActionTypes<E> => {
  const result: Partial<ActionTypes<E>> = {};
  for (const k in keys) {
    const key: E[keyof E] = keys[k];
    result[key] = createActionTypeName<E>(key);
  }
  return result as unknown as ActionTypes<E>;
};

const createAction = <
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
  K extends E[keyof E] = E[keyof E],
>
(
  type: ActionTypes<E>[K],
  key: K,
): Action<E, S, K> => (
  payload: S[K]['value'],
): ReturnType<Action<E, S, K>> => ({
  type,
  key,
  payload,
});

const createActions = <
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
>(
  actionTypes: ActionTypes<E>,
  keys: E,
): Actions<E, S> => {
  const result: Partial<Actions<E, S>> = {};
  for (const k in keys) {
    const key: E[keyof E] = keys[k];
    const actionType = actionTypes[key];
    result[key] = createAction<E, S>(actionType, key);
  }
  return result as unknown as Actions<E, S>;
};

const createActionName = <
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  K extends E[keyof E] = E[keyof E],
>(
  key: K,
): ActionName<E, K> => {
  const [first, ...letters] = key;
  const postFix = [first.toUpperCase(), ...letters].join('') as Capitalize<K>;
  return `update${postFix}`;
};

const createAliasedActions = <
  E extends { [key: string]: string },
  S extends MyState<E>,
>(
  actions: Actions<E, S>,
  keys: E,
): AliasedActions<E, S> => {
  const result: Partial<AliasedActions<E, S>> = {};
  for (const k in keys) {
    const key = keys[k];
    const name = createActionName<E>(key);
    result[name] = actions[key];
  }
  return result as unknown as AliasedActions<E, S>;
};

enum MyEnum {
  TEST = 'test1',
  TEST2 = 'test2',
}

const exampleState = {
  [MyEnum.TEST]: new Entry<string>(),
  [MyEnum.TEST2]: new Entry<number>(),
};

const actionTypes = createActionTypes<typeof MyEnum>(MyEnum);

const actions = createActions<typeof MyEnum, typeof exampleState>(actionTypes, MyEnum);

// This is the desired effect
const test = actions.test1('test');
const test2 = actions.test1(1); // TS2345: Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | undefined'.

// This is also the desired effect
const test3 = actions.test2('test'); // TS2345: Argument of type 'test' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | undefined'.
const test4 = actions.test2(1); // okay

// After changing the object so that the functions are named based on the key, type information is lost.
const aliasedActions = createAliasedActions(actions, MyEnum);

// This is not the intended effect!
aliasedActions.updateTest1(1); // okay
aliasedActions.updateTest1('1'); // okay
aliasedActions.updateTest2(1); // okay
aliasedActions.updateTest2('1'); // okay

/*
    TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | undefined'.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.
 */
// Typescript correctly throws an error on this, showing that it's not considering the param "any"
aliasedActions.updateTest2({});
```

Comment: Is this really a *minimal* [mre]? In my experience almost all TS issues like this can be demonstrated with code that fits on a single screenful of text without needing to scroll.  If you could possibly pare it down to just the minimum needed to show the error, possibly reformatting (e.g., use less vertical space) and removing aliases (e.g., `\`UPDATE_${Uppercase<K>}\`` probably doesn't need its own whole type alias, and one that depends on an unused type parameter `E` as well as `K`) and maybe even removing runtime code and just declare things with the types they need, it might help.

Comment: Like, [look at this code](https://tsplay.dev/w6pGGm).  I just spent the last ten minutes paring it down to what I think is the basic [mre] here, or at least it fits on my screen all at once.  Do you agree that this demonstrates the issue?  If so then please [edit] to use that instead.  If not what am I missing?

Comment: And, uh, [*why* can't you use `K` instead of `E[keyof E]`](https://tsplay.dev/w8XYVw)? What goes wrong when you try it? You say "it appears as though I can no longer use `K` as the third generic type parameter for `Action`" but I can't reproduce a problem and your code, while quite extensive, doesn't demonstrate the part which is apparently the crux of the problem .  I think I might have to disengage for a bit.

Comment: @jcalz Respectfully, I examined the code you posted for a minimally reproducible example. Where you declare `action` and `aliasedActions` with a specific type not using generics, it misses the entire point for this project, where the intention is to have the types for the state discerned completely from the initial state object. Yes, the issue is resolved easily by declaring exactly what actions and aliasActions should be, but that leaves the type definition hard-coded.

Comment: Your problem was after the part where you ran the functions, so I was just skipping it to get to the actual problem.  That certainly does not miss the point of the question (and is agnostic about your project, so whether it misses the point of it doesn't seem to be relevant to your question).  But, temporarily granting that the full example is necessary to demonstrate your issue, can you explain why you can't use `K` instead of `E[keyof E]`? [I still don't see the problem](https://tsplay.dev/mqYx2m).

Comment: @jcalz As for why I cannot use `K` instead of `E[keyof E]`, that is what I am trying to figure out. After asserting `K` as the template literal to use as a key, passing it into the generic for Action produces ````Action<E, S, `update${Capitalize<K>}`>````. I.e., the last type parameter no longer represents a specific item that is `E[keyof E]`.

Comment: If you could look at [this version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/mqYx2m) and point out a way in which it's not doing what you want, I would be grateful.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if I stumbled upon a bug in the version of Typescript (4.4.4) I am using because I got the result I described on my side. Still, the only thing that is the same is trouble assigning the action function to the collection inside `createAliasedActions`. I must have the type for the AliasedActions wrong somewhere. The TS playground does not match what I am getting in my build, which is that TS is okay with strings or numbers in the aliased functions.

Comment: How should we proceed here? Currently this doesn't seem to be a [mre].  [You can change the TS version in the playground to 4.4.4](https://tsplay.dev/NB8QbW) and it still behaves as desired. And your question isn't asking about the error inside `createAliasedActions`, right? If the issue can't be demonstrated then I guess we're stuck?

Comment: @jcalz I certainly appreciate your help, but I think we are stuck. Since I am getting different results in my dev environment versus the TS Playground, I will have to investigate environmental differences and fix those issues if need be. Although rare, I have seen errors that don't occur depending on the compilation option in the TS config. If that's the case, then you did actually help me get to the root of the problem.